# Find differences between two lists in EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two lists.

**Client List :** one of them receive from user (client)

**Server List :** one of them get from database .

I want to do 3 work on this lists .

**One :** Add  ( if data not exists in server List and exist in the client List )

**Two :** Remove data ( if exist in the server List and not exist in the client List )

**Three :** Update ( if data exist in server List and client Server and data has Changed )

This is my model:

```
public class CategoryPropertyDto
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string PropName { get; set; }
    public CategoryPropertyType CategoryPropertyType { get; set; }
}
```

the client send me the list of this model `CategoryPropertyDto`.

Now I write this code for adding data:

```
var currentValue = getAllPropByCategory.Result.Select(x => new CategoryPropertyDto
            {
                CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                CategoryPropertyType = x.CategoryPropertyType.CategoryPropertyType,
                Id = x.Id,
                PropName = x.PropName
            }).ToList();
            /// Add New Property
            var newProp = request.CategoryPropertyDtos.Where(x => x.Id == null).ToList();
            List<CategoryProperty> CategoryProperty = new List<CategoryProperty>();
            if (newProp.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in newProp)
                {
                    CategoryProperty.Add(new CategoryProperty(item.PropName, item.CategoryPropertyType, item.CategoryId));
                }
                await unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.CategoryPropertyRepository.AddBulkCategoryProperty(CategoryProperty, cancellationToken);
            }
```

and its worked well.

Now I want to find items for remove (exist in the server List but not exist in the clientList)

```
 var removeValue = currentValue.Except(request.CategoryPropertyDtos).ToList();
```

but it did not work and return all `currentValue`  and I don't know how can I find the items for update.

**How can I solve this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

> var removeValue = currentValue.Except(request.CategoryPropertyDtos).ToList();

This line does not work because in this case Except method compare References, not Values and obviously currentValue items have different references than client items.

**solution:**
You have to use Id in all cases (add, delete, update) as you already did for Add case.
So for example to find items to delete:

```
var ItemIdsToDelete = currentValue.Select(p => p.Id).Except(request.CategoryPropertyDtos.Select(p => p.Id)).ToList();
```

and delete items by id using method like this:

```
await unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.CategoryPropertyRepository.DeleteBulkCategoryPropertyById(ItemIdsToDelete, cancellationToken);
```

and you can do similar thing to find items that their ids exist in both client and server lists and update them.